# Trabalhando com IF = null no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu tenho uma consulta com join em que os dados podem nao existir em uma tabela fazendo com que o meu retorno seja nulo, quando este retorno for nulo, gostaria que ele fizesse outra consulta sem o join, segue o exemplo:

```
select 
a.*, b.Tabela2
from Tabela1 a
inner join Tabela2 b on b.Tabela2 = 
a.Tabela1
where nr_senha = '880'
order by dt_emissao DESC
```

se esse retorno for nulo por nao terem os dados na tabela2 quero que faça o select abaixo:
select
*
from Tabela1
where nr_senha = '880'
order by dt_emissao desc;

Comment: Será que o quer não é um `left join`? Caso seja null o resultado você pode usar o coalesce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu estava respondendo exatamente com a sugestão feita pelo @Danizavtz, ou seja:

- Faça `LEFT JOIN` (ou `RIGHT JOIN` dependendo da ordem) com ambas as tabelas, assim sempre retorna os dados da tabela principal e **se houver** dados nas outras retorna, ou retorna null;
- Use a função [`COALESCE()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-BR/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), que retorna o primeiro valor não null de uma lista de valores, e pode passar as colunas das tabelas

Aqui um exemplo:

```
select id, 
       coalesce(tabelaA.descricaoA, tabelaB.descricaoB) descricao
  from principal
  left join tabelaA on principal.id = tabelaA.idPrincipal
  left join tabelaB on principal.id = tabelaB.idPrincipal
```

Ou seja, se existir valor em "tabelaA" retorna "descricaoA", senão retorna "descricaoB" da "tabelaB".

Pode ver funcionando aqui: [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/efa93/1)

Também poderia fazer com a função `ISNULL`, mas para esse caso acho `COALESCE` semanaticamente melhor, mas segue o exemplo: `isnull(tabelaA.descricaoA, tabelaB.descricaoB)`

Comment: Obrigado amigo, acabei utilizando o ISNULL mesmo, mas obrigado pela dica! com certeza irei usar no proximo.